# Steam get user's email address

Tags: asp.net, openid, steam, steam-web-api

I am using an OpenId provider to let the user log into my site through steam. For when they register with additional information, I want to prefill their email address. However, I cannot seem to find a steam api for this. When I look at the claims, it just has steamid and friendly name. Then I thought to maybe use the webapi here:

http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUser/GetPlayerSummaries/v0002/

However when I provide my info this is all I get back:

```
"response": {
    "players": [
        {
            "steamid": "99999999999999999",
            "communityvisibilitystate": 3,
            "profilestate": 1,
            "personaname": "Something",
            "lastlogoff": 1437554243,
            "profileurl": "http://steamcommunity.com/id/Something/",
            "avatar": "https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/a4/a4a54b1e0a8b0b3b85b87f9e38fde784b3ce322d.jpg",
            "avatarmedium": "https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/a4/a4a54b1e0a8b0b3b85b87f9e38fde784b3ce322d_medium.jpg",
            "avatarfull": "https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/a4/a4a54b1e0a8b0b3b85b87f9e38fde784b3ce322d_full.jpg",
            "personastate": 0,
            "realname": "tom",
            "primaryclanid": "103582791438339107",
            "timecreated": 1084138831,
            "personastateflags": 0,
            "loccountrycode": "US",
            "locstatecode": "FL",
            "loccityid": 1020
        }
    ]

}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Steam does not expose the email address.

That information is PII (personally identifiable information).  As such, it is subject to various legal controls (depending on the jurisdiction).

Additionally, Steam would quickly lose customers if anyone with a Steam API key could retrieve email addresses for Steam customers and start spamming them.

Comment: I would think name and city would also be personally identifiable, but yeah agreed, their API exposes what their API exposes, can't get the info if it isn't there.

Comment: This is what I suspected. I can ask for the email address an make it optional.

Comment: City is never considered PII, though some jurisdictions consider ZIP/Postal Code to be.  Name is a bit of a grey area.  I would not expose a real name, but I'm sure Steam did their own analysis of the risks and benefits.

Comment: ah ok, cool... so i'll just drop steam again as social provider and now i also understand why we never see steam as a social provider in probably all login-boxes i've ever seen... funny that almost _any_ oauth2 provider is exposing the email which is exactly the same PII thingy - not really an argument to me